# Are the only $b$ such that $b^2 + 4c$ and $b^2 - 4c$ are both perfect squares primes of the form $4k + 1$?

Tags: number-theory

And of course, multiples of primes of the form $4k + 1$

$b, c, k$ are positive integers.

Ran into a math problem essentially involving this, just curious. I observed it to hold for the first $50$ integers, but not sure past that nor how to prove it.

Does it have to do with Fermat's "Christmas" theorem ($p = x^2 + y^2$ iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number $b$ need not be prime. We have $65^2+3696=89^2$ and $65^2-3696=23^2$.

A boring kind of example is $10^2-96=4$, $10^2+96=14^2$.

**Remark:** One can generate arbitrarily many non-boring  examples using $(r,s,b)$ such that $(r,s,b)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple and $b$ is not prime. Any such example requires $b$ to have at least two not necessarily distinct prime divisors of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: I was asking why, not just for examples. But I actually figured it out on my own (I think).

Comment: Addressing your remark, I'm not looking for $r^2 + s^2 = b^2$, rather $r^2 + s^2 = 2b^2$.

Comment: Yes, you are. To keep my notation, you are looking for $x^2+y^2=2b^2$. Take $r$ and $s$ such that $r^2+s^2=b^2$. Then let $x=r+s$ and $y=r-s$. We get $x^2+y^2=2b^2$.